# \widering over \bar not working

Tags: accents, yhmath

I need to write a topology expression involving the interior of the closure of a set. For the interior of a (not simple) set I'm using the macro `\widering` from `yhmath` package and it works fine if I write the closure with `\overline`. But I'd like to use instead `\bar` if the set involved is simple.

Here are a couple of examples. What I want to achieve is an expression like the left ones, but using `\bar` or anything that draws a shorter line over the simple set. Or another package (or macro) that provides a `\widering` version that not cause this issues. Any idea will be welcome.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage   {amssymb}
\usepackage   {yhmath} % \widering

\begin{document}
My problem is the second expression:
\[ 
  E \setminus \widering{\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \overline{A}_n} \ne % all good
  E \setminus \widering{\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \bar{A}_n}.         % not so good
\]

Another simpler example:
\[
  \widering{A\overline{B}C} \ne
  \widering{A\bar{B}C}.
\]
\end{document}
```

And here you can see what happens:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definition of `\widering` is not really good, because it puts the ring too high.

Also, nested accents always give problems, if the outer accent has to be placed over complex formulas.

Here's a proposal for a fixed `\widering`, that also complies with the requirement for the nested accents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[nowidering]{yhmath} % \widering

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\widering}[1]{\mathpalette\widering@{#1}}
\newcommand{\widering@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1#2$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$\m@th#1\wideparen{\copy\z@}$}%
  \mathring{\copy\tw@}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

My problem is the second expression:
\[ 
  E \setminus \widering{\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \overline{A}_n} \ne % all good
  E \setminus \widering{\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \bar{A}_n}.         % not so good
\]

Another simpler example:
\[
  \widering{A\overline{B}C} \ne
  \widering{A\bar{B}C}.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now it works perfect, thanks!!! :-D